# How to prevent WordDelimiterFilterFactory to split on "."(dot)

Tags: solr, solr4

I want to use WordDelimiterFilterFactory for requirement like :

```
input : 500bc

i want to search it with "500bc" or just "500"
```

for that i used **WordDelimiterFilterFactory** with :

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  preserveOriginal="1"/>
```

**but now issue is it also tokenize with .(dot) like query for "6.25" will also give "25" as result**

how i can stop   WordDelimiterFilterFactory from tokenizing with .(dot) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used

```
<filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"  generateWordParts="0"   preserveOriginal="1" types="wdfftypes.txt" />
```

in wdfftypes.txt I puted

> **. => DIGIT**

How it works : now solr will treat . as Digit and as 6.25 all are digits WordDelimiterFilterFactory will not tokenize 6.25

Comment: This could possibly cause you some trouble with the way other dots are treated, eg. what happens in case of an end-of-sentence dot?

Comment: @spyk i have no idea about that but sure will share once i will get details about it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `generateNumberParts="0"` parameter in your filter declaration, that will prevent the filter from splitting numbers on punctuation. You can have a look here for more details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-WordDelimiterFilter